# Custom parameters on recommended view_item Ecommerce event

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

Another day, another GTM question.

I am using Google's recommended e-commerce view_item event to track how many times an item (a Dance Event / Course in this case) gets viewed. I tried to use the recommended item parameters to hold all the information possible, but I asked the developer to add some custom parameters to the item object (event_date, instructor_name, etc..).

I can see the custom parameters in the Data Layer and on the GTM Tag Assistant, but I cannot see it on the GA4 Debug View. From what I understand, Google let's you add up to 27 custom parameters in the Items array, so I am not entirely sure why the custom params would not show up, however, they only allow for 10 Item-Scoped dimensions (which in my opinion it's way to little, maybe I'm seeing this in the wrong way)

I can see the custom parameters in the Data Layer and on the GTM Tag Assistant, but I cannot see them on the GA4 Debug View. From what I understand, Google lets you add up to p, however, they only allow for 10 Item-Scoped dimensions (which in my opinion it's way too little, maybe I'm seeing this the wrong way)

https://imgur.com/a/CB33Bz5

Thanks everyone

Added the custom parames to the items array. Can actually see them in the Data Layer, but cannot see them in the GA4 Debug View.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: So did you create the corresponding item scope parameter in your setting? Yes for free plan GA4 now only provide 10 custom item scope parameters.  But GA4 360 can create up to 25.

Comment: Hello! When I created the tag, I wasn't aware that I needed to create an item-scope paramter on GA4. I have now created it and waiting for GA4 to pick up the changes.

Just a note. My tag configuration does not have any event parameters. I only enabled the "Send ecommerce data". Do I have to add the custom params here as well?

Comment: No you don't. I think you can see the parameter is getting value right?

Comment: So I figured what the "issue" is. Not sure if I'm dumb, but on the custom reports on GA4, I had to add a metric (additionally to the custom param) to visualize the item-scoped values.

I thought that only by setting the param as one of the report dimensions would work, but apparently you also need a metric. :smh:

Comment: Not really sure about the issue. Let's say you add an item scope parameter call `instructor_name`. Also already created in the GA4 setting. Then you want to check in explorer. Yes you need to import the `instructor_name` as dimension. And you can check the event count or session `metric` with that dimension. Not sure why you need to create another metric for it?